# How do I see my movie viewing history on Amazon?

Tags: amazon

I have googled a lot on this, cannot find anything in the Amazon site, or app, that shows movies I have watched.

Answer (score 2):

- log in to your account
- click the **Your Account** link on the top bar
- on the resulting page scroll down to **Personalization**
- click on **Improve Your Recommendations**
- then on the left menu click on **Videos You've Watched**

quick link: **[US](https://www.amazon.com/gp/yourstore/iyr/ref=pd_ys_iyr_edit_watched?ie=UTF8&collection=watched)** / **[UK](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/yourstore/iyr/ref=pd_ys_iyr_edit_watched?ie=UTF8&collection=watched)**

Comment: outdated as of 2021

Answer (score 2):

If you are an Amazon Prime member:

1. Click the "Your Account" button
2. Click "Prime Video settings"
3. Click "Watch History"

Here's a visual:
[image: screenshot of steps described above]

Comment: outdated as of 2021